# How to retrieve color from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Container which color I want to change depending on the Color chosen. The color is stored in my Firebase Database. I'm just struggling to retrieve the int form the firebase to change the color. Okay so i make a Container and in the container is information. There is 3 options then to choose from when you click the blue button it changes the container to blue, same with yellow and pink. Each button color has a number (int 0, 1, 2) which is stored in my Firebase. So when the person clicks on blue (int 0) it saves it in the Firebase (Color to int basically). So i want to retrieve that int so that it changes the color of the container on the screen.
Get Background Color:

```
_getClr(int no) {
    switch (no) {
      case 0:
        return blue;
      case 1:
        return pink;
      case 2:
        return yellow;
      default:
        return blue;
    }
  }
```

Container:

```
return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 110,
      // color: Database Ref for the int to change color
      child: Column(//Info that appears on the container)
```

Retrieve Data:

```
Expanded(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query: dbRef,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                Animation<double> animation, int index) {
              Map DB = snapshot.value as Map;
             

              return Container(DB: DB);
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: can you please give some more information about what you want to do exactly? And what is int value?

Comment: Okay so i make a Container and in the container is information. There is 3 options then to choose from when you click the blue button it changes the container to blue, same with yellow and pink. Each button color has a number (int 0, 1, 2) which is stored in my Firebase. So when the person clicks on blue (int 0) it saves it in the Firebase (Color to int basically). So i want to retrieve that int so that it changes the color of the container on the screen. @SagarRAnghan

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do is to change the `color: Color...` property in my `BoxDecoration` to `color: _getClr(DB['Color'])`